# A way to display Google Analytics data for the currently logged-in Wordpress user's website?

Tags: php, google-analytics, wordpress, woocommerce

Long story short, I run a web development company, and when my clients log into OUR Wordpress site, I'd like to be able to provide some some basic, high-level analytics of THEIR website (the site we built for them and set up analytics for).

We cater primarily toward small businesses and the GA platform would completely overwhelm them.  We already manage payments, hosting subscriptions, one-off purchases, etc.. on our site anyway via Woocommerce, so ideally what I'd like to do is enhance that My Account section to include a few personalized modules such as analytics, new newsletter signups, social media likes, etc..

A sort of one-stop-shop if you will but to do this, ideally, I'd need dynamic plugins that can tailor the data displayed to the currently logged in user.  I could manually tie the user account to the GA profile on the backend. I'm just not sure how to display it.

But it starts with the analytics so I was curious if anyone knows of any plugins or tools that would make implementing something like this less painful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Google Analytics Dashboard for WP](http://wordpress.org/plugins/google-analytics-dashboard-for-wp/) plugin for displaying a GA widget in the **Administration Dashboard** and also to show some basic stats such as views, uniqueViews and top searches, on **frontend**, at the end of each article to authorized users.

Comment: I actually ended up using a really cool library called OOCharts.  I had a clean dashboard up and running in under a day.  Points for trying though.